# query take too long while counting

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

i try to paginate a million of object using neo4j and spring data . My programme  excute two queries : 
the first match the data . the second count all elements matching my restrictions. but the last query take a lot of time.

---

This is some part of paginate function :

```
 @Autowired
Neo4jOperations template;`


StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(" match (n:Domain) where n.isPrincipale={isPrincipale} ");
mapOfVars.put("isPrincipale", true);
  if (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("mydom")
      && !request.getParameter("mydom").isEmpty()) {
            query.append(" and n.domain  =~ {mydom}");
            mapOfVars.put("mydom",".*(?i)"+request.getParameter("mydom")+".*");
}
```

the probleme is here :

```
iTotalRecords = Integer.valueOf((template.query(query.toString() + " return count(n) as count", mapOfVars)).queryResults().iterator().next().get("count").toString());
```

After counting i get the matching results :

```
query.append(" 
     return n.domain as domain, n.hasDmarc as dmarc , 
     n.spf_action    as spf, n.updatedAt as updatedAt , 
     n.existValue as exst , id(n) as id 
     skip  {start} limit {displayCount}");
 mapOfVars.put("start", iDisplayStart);
 mapOfVars.put("displayCount", iDisplayCount);

Iterable<Map<String, Object>> domains = template.query(query.toString(), mapOfVars);
```

Comment: Please share more detail, otherwise, you can't be helped. There are ways for fast counting but without providing details ...

Comment: can you check now the edited post please.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have an index (or uniqueness constraint) on `:Domain(isPrincipale)`, then neo4j will have to scan all `Domain` nodes to find the matching ones.

To create an index, run this query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Domain(isPrincipale);
```

Note, though, that using an index helps the most if only a relatively small percentage of the same-labelled nodes have the `isPrincipale` value you want to match. Unfortunately, since the `isPrincipale` value is a boolean (and therefore has only 2 possible values), indexing may not help much.

[UPDATE]

The main problem is that you are performing a full query to get all matching `Domain` nodes *every time* (both when counting them, and in each pagination step). This is obviously very expensive. It would be better (in speed terms) to just get all the matching nodes and then do the counting and pagination locally.

Another way to speed up things (but probably to a lesser extent than the above) is to eliminate the expensive regexp string comparisons to find the matching `Domain` nodes. If you know beforehand the set of possible `mydom` strings, you can just store the relationships between those strings and the appropriate `Domain` nodes in the DB. For example, you can create `DomainName` nodes, and create `HAS_DOMAIN` relationships between each of them and the appropriate `Domain` nodes. That way, your first code snippet could become this and result in faster queries:

```
@Autowired
Neo4jOperations template;`

StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
String mydom = request.getParameter("mydom");
if (mydom != null && !mydom.isEmpty()) {
  query.append("MATCH (:DomainName {name: $mydom})-[:HAS_DOMAIN]->(n:Domain) ");
  mapOfVars.put("mydom", mydom);
} else {
  query.append("MATCH (n:Domain) ");
}
query.append("WHERE n.isPrincipale=$isPrincipale")
mapOfVars.put("isPrincipale", true);
```

Comment: already created. also my query  can include a restriction on any domain's properties. so i don t like to create index on all properties

Comment: what do you thing about cahe in this situation ? because the main probleme is that neo4j check all domain while counting.

Comment: Hi cybersam, thank you for your response. i paginate the domain object. i don't get all domain. but the expensive query is the count of all of them. i will try to use the cache of neo4j.